# Where are the AspNetCore.SignalR release notes?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-signalr

We have an issue with frequent disconnects and are using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR` in version `1.0.3`.

There's a version 1.0.4 and 1.1.0 so I thought I'd check the release notes to see if it might be an issue that was fixed.

However, I can not for the life of me find any release notes for these packages.

Nuget points at an archived repo that contains the releases but no notes or even tags for issues that were fixed in it. The new repo, AspNet.Core, has only its own release notes that do not mention the SiganlR package or which version is used at all. No tags or wiki entries or markdown docs that I could find.

It shouldn't be this hard to find release notes; am I cursed with blindness or are they really not to be had?

Comment: here is the list of [commits in 1.1.0](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/compare/1.1.0...master)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems currently the only maintained method is by visiting the releases in the Asp.Net Core repo then click on release notes of the required release then search on singleR,
and check out the `Blog Roundup` and `ASP.NETCore` under `Additional fixes in this release`

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/releases

[image]

Answer (score 0):

New url for notes (signalr core):

https://github.com/dotnet/core/tree/main/release-notes